# Radical choice for 安全

Tags: word-choice, glyph-origin, radicals

A simple question, why does the lower half of 安全 (safe), have the female character: 女 ？

Is it implying that safety pertains only to females being secure? Or is there no such implication?

I'd like to know why 女 was chosen

Comment: Baidu answer.If you can read Chinese: 宀mián是家室的意思，甲骨文字体“女”是呈跪坐姿态，字义为女子能够安坐家中，是因为外无祸患，内无争端。

Comment: @dan sorry. I can't read Chinese that well would you mind translating ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Splitting the character 安, we get 宀 + 女.

In oracle bone script, 宀 stands for house, and 女 means bride. The whole caracter means "bride in new house" (i.e. marriage).

In traditional Chinese culture, marrying a girl is a *huge* settlement in a man's life, so 安 means 安定 (settled), 安心 (relieved).

[Reference](http://www.vividict.com/WordInfo.aspx?id=3058) is in full Chinese (so it's a bit hard for learners to read).

Answer (score 2):

The comment by @dan is correct -「安」depicts a kneeling girl/woman in a building, indicating the meaning *sitting peacefully* > *peace, quiet*. It does not mean *bride in new house.*

> Please don't use Vividict as a resource. It contains decidedly non-mainstream interpretations.

---

「安」was originally composed of「宀」(*building*),「女」(picture of a kneeling *girl/woman*), and **an extra mark located around the area between the woman's heels and buttocks**, emphasising that the woman is in a kneeling/sitting position.

## <kbd>[商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)
[甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)
[image]
[鄴](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)3下・44.8
[合集29378](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=29378&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou)
[金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
[image]
公貿鼎
[集成2719](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=2719&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty)
[簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips)
[image]
[睡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuihudi_Qin_bamboo_texts)・[法](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/QinwenziReference)168</kbd>
　<kbd>[西漢](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_dynasty#Western_Han)
[篆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script)
[image]
長安鋗</kbd>
　<kbd>[東漢](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_dynasty#Eastern_Han)
[隸](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerical_script)
[image]
[孔宙碑](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/%E5%AD%94%E5%AE%99%E7%A2%91)陰</kbd>
　<kbd>現代
[楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
[image]</kbd>

*Red line in the first form points to the small mark, which later became exaggerated.*

The mark started being omitted in the Warring States period and completely disappeared after the Western Han.

> Shapes that look like「安」before the Warring States without the mark may be considered to be a variant of「賓」instead.

---

## References:

- 季旭昇《說文新證》
- 小學堂
- 國學大師